# How to number each line in the output using a for loop?

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoveCS
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int noTimesPrinted;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many times should the message be printed: ");
        noTimesPrinted = scan.nextInt();

        int count = 1;
        while (count <= noTimesPrinted) 
        {
            System.out.println(" I love Computer Science!!");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

1. Instead of using constant LIMIT, ask the user how many times the message should be printed. You will need to declare a variable to store the user’s response and use that variable to control the loop. (Remember that all caps is used only for constants!)

I HAVE COMPLETED PART1. I AM STUCK ON PART2. How do I get the number sequence??

2. Number each line in the output, and add a message at the end of the loop that says how many times the message was printed. So if the user enters 3, your program should print this:

   ```
    1 I love Computer Science!!
    2 I love Computer Science!!
    3 I love Computer Science!!
    Printed this message 3 times.
   ```
3. If the message is printed N times, compute and print the sum of the numbers from 1 to N.
   So for the example above, the last line would now read:

   ```
   Printed this message 3 times. The sum of the numbers from 1 to 3 is 6.
   ```

   Note that you will need to add a variable to hold the sum.

Comment: Here's a hint.  You know that `count` variable you have?  You're going to have to use that in your output somehow.

Comment: Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) and pay attention to the bit labeled "Concatenating Strings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices. You could use `String` concatenation,

```
int count = 1;
while (count <= noTimesPrinted) 
{
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(count) + " I love Computer Science!!");
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Printed this message " + noTimesPrinted + " times");
```

Or with `printf` and (since you said you wanted a `for` loop) something like

```
for (int count = 1; count <= noTimesPrinted; count++) {
    System.out.printf("%d I love Computer Science!!%n", count);
}
System.out.printf("Printed this message %d times%n", noTimesPrinted);
```

Comment: Oh no wonder I was hitting a problem! I wasn't converting using `toString`!!

Thank you so much!

Comment: @MonaRamesh You don't have to convert the number by yourself, just call `System.out.println(count + " I love Computer Science!!");` and the `println` method will handle it for you.